# What did Thomas Mann yield in negotiations with Nazis in 1933?

Tags: 20th-century, nazi-germany, germany, literature

The following is from the article on [Golo Mann](http://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Golo_Mann) (1909 – 1994) in the [German Wikipedia](http://de.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Golo_Mann&oldid=140174663) (translation courtesy of Google Translate). Golo Mann was the son of German novelist and 1929 Nobel Prize in Literature laureate [Thomas Mann](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thomas_Mann) (1875 – 1955).

> In January 1933, Adolf Hitler came to power. For Thomas Mann, who had
> made no secret of his dislike of National Socialism, and in particular
> for Golo Mann's older siblings Klaus and Erika Mann, this was the time
> to emigrate. While the parents were staying on a lecture tour abroad,
> of which she did not return to Golo Mann attended in April 1933 at the
> Munich House, organized the departure of three younger siblings and
> brought the bank balances of the parents to safety. Thomas Mann
> asked his son bundle of notes and oilcloth notebook - they contained
> Thomas Mann's diaries of the Twenties - to stow away in a suitcase and
> means of forwarding by rail to Lugano to send with the urgent
> request: "I count on your discretion, that you are [not going to read them]."
>
> Hans Holzner, the driver of the family and secret
> follower of Hitler, offered to give up the case. Instead, he handed
> over the bag of the Bavarian political police. When it was still not
> arrived three weeks later, the seizure was near, and Thomas Mann
> implored the lawyer Valentin Heins to try anything to [obtain them back]. Golo Mann describes the panic came into his father: "[They] will
> publish it in the People's Observer. [They] ruin everything, they'll ruin
> me. My life can not be all right." Heins reached in negotiations a few
> weeks later [their release].

Do we know what Thomas Mann (via his attorney [Valentin Heims](http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Valentin_Heins_%28Rechtsanwalt%29)) yielded in these negotiations with Hitler's Nazis? (The article cites Golo's Mann's autobiography, which I do not have ready, as source for the last sentence.) I assume its fair to refer to negotiations with Nazis, because the article identifies the driver as a follower of Adolf Hitler. Thomas Mann was about to emigrate to the U.S.